# get icloud password from activated device

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, password

Here is the story ..
My friend bought an iphone 5S ..
Later he found that it's linked to icloud account and it wasn't verified ..
So, he asked me to help him remove the account .. And i couldn't ..
So, i told him that there is nothing i can do for him and he should use the device in this condition till someone find a solution ..
Next day i met him .. And his iphone has no icloud !!
He told me that he found a guy in a mobile shop who did it for him ..
That guy didn't just removed the account .. He also gave it's password to my friend !!
And i've tested the account myself .. !!
My friend also told me that he did it in just 15 min .. !!

I know you can extract account password from an encrypted backup ..
But it's not that simple .. And not everyone can do it !!

So, have someone here knows about getting icloud password from activated device ..
Or can explain what that dude did to my friend's iphone ??

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even if what you're suggesting were possible, it shouldn't be allowed for discussion here because it has the potential to circumvent a trusted security feature.